# How to not Open Accordion by default

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok I do not know javascript so much, so I have created a accordion by searching in google. but the problem is the first item of the accordion is always open up, even if I do not use "toggle-active" class. The accordion works perfectly though, I mean if I use this "toggle-active" class in item number 3 for an example, then the item number 3 is open up at default.

but my problem is I have only one item & I want to open the accordion item, when it clicks only, not open by default. How can I do it?

here is the code guys:

```
jQuery(".toggle-item").each(function() {
        jQuery(this).find('.toggle-active').siblings('.toggle-inner').slideDown(300);                           
    });

    jQuery(".toggle-item").on("click", ".toggle-title", function() { 
        var thisItem = jQuery(this); 
        var parentdiv = thisItem.parent('div').parent('div');
        var active = thisItem.parent('div').find('.toggle-inner').css('display');

        if (jQuery(parentdiv).attr('class') === 'accordion') {
            if (active !== 'none' ) { 
                jQuery(parentdiv).find('.toggle-item .toggle-inner').slideUp(300);
                thisItem.toggleClass('toggle-active');
            } else {
                jQuery(parentdiv).find('.toggle-item .toggle-inner').slideUp(300);
                jQuery(parentdiv).find('.toggle-item .toggle-title').removeClass('toggle-active');

                thisItem.toggleClass('toggle-active');
                thisItem.siblings('.toggle-inner').slideDown(300);
            }
        } else {
            thisItem.toggleClass('toggle-active');
            thisItem.siblings('.toggle-inner').slideToggle(300);
        }

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: did you try to remove first 3 lines of your code? This lines go over all items and perform `slideDown()` on the active item

Comment: @JohnnyAW if I do this, then the accordion does not work anymore.

Comment: what do you mean by "does not work"? what is the error in the console?

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: parentdiv is not defined"

Comment: btw. do yourself a favor and don't try to reinvent the wheel: https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 0):

Use http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-collapsible

This is a jquery accordion widget that you can use.

$( ".toggle-item" ).accordion("option", { 
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
});